# json dict - python how to access

Tags: python, json, dictionary

i know, this might be easy, but i am stuck whatsoever.. this is the `data`

```
{ u'job_27301': [{u'auto_approve': u'0',
                 u'body_src': u'some text1'}],

  u'job_27302': [{u'auto_approve': u'0',
                 u'body_src': u'some text2'}],

  u'job_27303': [{u'auto_approve': u'0',
                 u'body_src': u'some text3'}] }
```

I have this dictionary of lists.

how can I loop over it and get `body_src` from the value list in each step? I tried

```
for k, d in data:
    print d[k]
```

to get the list part, but it is saying `too many values to unpack`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d={ u'job_27301': [{u'auto_approve': u'0',
                 u'body_src': u'some text1'}],

  u'job_27302': [{u'auto_approve': u'0',
                 u'body_src': u'some text2'}],

  u'job_27303': [{u'auto_approve': u'0',
                 u'body_src': u'some text3'}] }

for k,v in d.iteritems(): # items in python 3
    print(v[0]["body_src"])
```

Or just the values:

```
for v in d.itervalues(): # values in python 3
    print(v[0]["body_src"])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error message because when you iterate directly over a `dict` you only get the keys.

So you could do this:

```
for k in data: 
    print data[k][0]['body_src']
```

**output**

```
some text1
some text3
some text2
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to iterate over the dict `(key,item)`, you can use `data.items()` or [`iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems):

```
>>> for k,d in data.iteritems():
...     print d[0][u'body_src']
...
some text1
some text3
some text2
```

When doing `for k,d in data:` you try to iterate over the keys only:

```
>>> for i in data:
...   print i
...
job_27301
job_27303
job_27302
```